# JXMapViewer2 mouse and key-events

Tags: mouseevent, keyboard-events

Have succesfully managed to add the JXMapViewer2 mapKit into a form as a widget. Map seems to work fine, and so does the zoom button, but it doesn't seem to have any (activated at least) support for keyboard or mouse-events. Neither does there seem to be any documentation of how (and where) to fix this. Any ideas?

PS: Project set up with NetBeans 7.2 with some help from the GUI-wizard.